# Wordpress dynamic footer widgets - Show second widget area only if one widget is existing otherwise show 1

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, widget

I'm creating a dynamic widget area in the footer of my WordPress theme.

What I'm trying to do is,
Create 4 widgets, but only show the next if one is existing.

so by default, I will see one widget called footer one

if we add footer one footer 2 option will show up, but in the footer, we will see one footer widget if we add the second widget in footer 2 we will see widget 3. if we add a widget in footer 3 we will see footer 4.

I need to style if only footer 1 exist width 100%
if 2 exist footer 1 50 %. footer 2 50%

if 3 exists footer 1 33% footer 2 33% . footer 3 33%

if 4 exist footer 1 25% footer 2 25% footer 3 25% footer 4 25%

Important,
I managed to make this work. but if I still couldn't make the other widgets show up only if the parent one is populated.

here is my code:

```
    <div class="footer-widgets">

    <?php
    /* The footer widget area is triggered if any of the areas
     * have widgets. So let's check that first.
     *
     * If none of the sidebars have widgets, then let's bail early.
     */
    if (   ! is_active_sidebar( 'first-footer-widget-area'  )
        && ! is_active_sidebar( 'second-footer-widget-area' )
        && ! is_active_sidebar( 'third-footer-widget-area'  )
        && ! is_active_sidebar( 'fourth-footer-widget-area' )
    )
        return;

    if (   is_active_sidebar( 'first-footer-widget-area'  )
        && is_active_sidebar( 'second-footer-widget-area' )
        && is_active_sidebar( 'third-footer-widget-area'  )
        && is_active_sidebar( 'fourth-footer-widget-area' )
    ) : ?>

    <aside class="fatfooter" role="complementary">
        <div class="first quarter left widget-area">
            <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'first-footer-widget-area' ); ?>
        </div><!-- .first .widget-area -->

        <div class="second quarter widget-area">
            <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'second-footer-widget-area' ); ?>
        </div><!-- .second .widget-area -->

        <div class="third quarter widget-area">
            <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'third-footer-widget-area' ); ?>
        </div><!-- .third .widget-area -->

        <div class="fourth quarter right widget-area">
            <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'fourth-footer-widget-area' ); ?>
        </div><!-- .fourth .widget-area -->
    </aside><!-- #fatfooter -->

    <?php 
    elseif ( is_active_sidebar( 'first-footer-widget-area'  )
        && is_active_sidebar( 'second-footer-widget-area' )
        && is_active_sidebar( 'third-footer-widget-area'  )
        && ! is_active_sidebar( 'fourth-footer-widget-area' )
    ) : ?>
    <aside class="fatfooter" role="complementary">
        <div class="first one-third left widget-area">
            <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'first-footer-widget-area' ); ?>
        </div><!-- .first .widget-area -->

        <div class="second one-third widget-area">
            <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'second-footer-widget-area' ); ?>
        </div><!-- .second .widget-area -->

        <div class="third one-third right widget-area">
            <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'third-footer-widget-area' ); ?>
        </div><!-- .third .widget-area -->

    </aside><!-- #fatfooter -->

    <?php
    elseif ( is_active_sidebar( 'first-footer-widget-area'  )
        && is_active_sidebar( 'second-footer-widget-area' )
        && ! is_active_sidebar( 'third-footer-widget-area'  )
        && ! is_active_sidebar( 'fourth-footer-widget-area' )
    ) : ?>
    <aside class="fatfooter" role="complementary">
        <div class="first half left widget-area">
            <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'first-footer-widget-area' ); ?>
        </div><!-- .first .widget-area -->

        <div class="second half right widget-area">
            <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'second-footer-widget-area' ); ?>
        </div><!-- .second .widget-area -->

    </aside><!-- #fatfooter -->

    <?php
    elseif ( is_active_sidebar( 'first-footer-widget-area'  )
        && ! is_active_sidebar( 'second-footer-widget-area' )
        && ! is_active_sidebar( 'third-footer-widget-area'  )
        && ! is_active_sidebar( 'fourth-footer-widget-area' )
    ) :
    ?>
    <aside class="fatfooter" role="complementary">
        <div class="first full-width widget-area">
            <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'first-footer-widget-area' ); ?>
        </div><!-- .first .widget-area -->

    </aside><!-- #fatfooter -->


    <?php //end of all sidebar checks.
    endif;?>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the If else in Wordpress PHP and can print CSS on its basis... Just refer to a hook which Returns the Number of Active Widgets...

This can help you building a function to get active widgets: https://generatewp.com/snippet/2V0V0gy/

Thanks!